# Merging Several Revisions - Management Issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Here's the scenario:

1) I've got a branchA
2) I've got a trunkA

both of these are unrelated meaning they have different paths that lead up to them.  BranchA was a copy of trunkA at one point in time.

So consequently when working on trunkA as it being used as the core dev trunk, I've been asked to merge certain changes to branchA so that it also has those code changes to some of our code code files.

Ok fine, I choose merge via revision range in the Tortoise dialog.  But then here's the thing.    Either I'm not being smart on my change sets (my repo sets) that I check in, or I do not know if maybe there's an option to exclude certain files in a RANGE of revisions.

Beause the problem is, there are times that I'll do some cleanup on classes that are ones I've dove into while coding during the time I"ve worked on a certain story.  So I clean stuff up like remove unused using statments, etc. which is what every dev should be doing (boyscout rule).

The problem is when I do that I think it probably dilutes.  Meaning I really should probably segregate out cleanup changes in its own commit.

Because the problem is, if I'm merging a range of revisions and I've done "other cleanup", I may not want to include some of that cleanup at the time I'm merging some of our core file changes to branchA.  Maybe I just want to move a certain story but problem is hey, I also included in some of those repo#s some other files I changed to clean them up.

I guess my question is, or more verification is that I probably need to just be cleaner on my commits.  Segregate things out solidly.  If it's a bunch of cleanup changes "around" the set of classes you were working on, wait and commit those in their own commit instance (own repo#).  That way whenever I do range merges I get exactly what I intended.  I don't think svn has a way to weed those files out in certain repo#s during a range merge.

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to merge a range of revisions from TrunkA to BranchA. But, your local Working Copy of BranchA is having uncommitted changes (related to the cleanup story you are handling) and you want to do commit of these changes separate from the commit after merge right?

If that is the problem, you can have a solution like this.

- Checkout a new working copy of BranchA (call it WC2) and perform the merge of range of revisions here.
- Then commit it. After that go back to the working copy where you are performing the clean up story (call it WC1).
- Do SVN update in WC1. It will get the merge changes you committed from WC2 updated here.
- There gets the real solution. There are three major scenarios we need to look into which can happen for each file in this Update.

The scenarios are us follows:

1. **File not changed in WC1 & File updated in TrunkA** - This is again not causing any problem because, the local file is not changed and it will just get the latest updates from the server.
2. **File changed in WC1 (uncommitted) & File not updated in TrunkA** - This will not get any problem since there is nothing happening in the Update for these files and your cleanup changes is intact.
3. **File changed in WC1 (uncommitted) & File updated in TrunkA** - This is one is going to get into SVN Conflict during the Update process. Then you can go into this one by one and fix the Conflict. That is the one going to get the time consumed here.

After this just complete your cleanup story in WC1 and commit that later.

That separate out both your tasks in commit history.

Comment: no local code has stuff that WAS committed related to changes in some of those repo #s

Comment: so lets say I am merging revisions 22, 24, and 25.   They are for some story I'm working on.  But in say 24, as I was developing, I noticed some unused using statements, maybe I changed some initializers to use class initializers in C# for exampole, etc. just routine cleanup in other classes that are not really related to my code then I'm thinking I need to wait and check those cleanup items into their own commit (own repo #) so that when I do get to the point of wanting to merge Story # whatever, I don't have to worry aobut in some cases I may not want to include some of the files I cleaned

Comment: what is this repo #s? I never heard of this in SVN terminology. Either you mean revision # or repository link I suppose. Please clarify this.